# Конфигурация nginx для стабильной работы сайта

Tags: nginx

При такой конфигурации nginx, сайт загружается через раз. Один раз загружается полностью, другой раз выдает

## 502 Bad Gateway

---

### nginx

Конфигурация nginx:

```
# Определяем пользователя, под которым работает nginx
user www-data;

 # Определяем количество рабочих процессов автоматически
 # Параметр auto поддерживается только начиная с версий 1.3.8 и 1.2.5.
worker_processes auto;


 # Определяем, куда писать лог ошибок и уровень логирования
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

 # Задаём файл, в котором будет храниться номер (PID) основного процесса
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    # Устанавливает максимальное количество соединений одного рабочего процесса. Следует выбирать значения от 1024 до 4096.
    # Как правило, число устанавливают в зависимости от числа ядер процессора по принципу n * 1024. Например, 2 ядра дадут worker_connections 2048.
    worker_connections  1024;

    # Метод обработки соединений. Наличие того или иного метода определяется платформой.
    # Как правило, NGINX сам умеет определять оптимальный метод, однако, его можно указать явно.
    # use epoll - используется в Linux 2.6+
    # use kqueue - FreeBSD 4.1+, OpenBSD 2.9+, NetBSD 2.0 и Mac OS X
    use epoll;


    # Будет принимать максимально возможное количество соединений 
    #multi_accept on;
}


http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # Куда писать лог доступа и уровень логирования
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    # Используется, если количество имен серверов большое
    #server_names_hash_max_size 1200;
    #server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;


    ### Обработка запросов ###

    # Метод отправки данных sendfile более эффективен, чем стандартный метод read+write 
    sendfile on;
    # Будет отправлять заголовки и и начало файла в одном пакете 
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;


    ### Информация о файлах ###

    # Максимальное количество файлов, информация о которых будет содержаться в кеше
    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    # Через какое время информация будет удалена из кеша
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    # Кеширование информации о тех файлах, которые были использованы хотя бы 2 раза
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    # Кеширование информации об отсутствующих файлах
    open_file_cache_errors on;


    # Удаляем информацию об nginx в headers
    server_tokens off;

    # Будет ждать 30 секунд перед закрытием keepalive соединения 
    keepalive_timeout 30s;    
    ## Максимальное количество keepalive запросов от одного клиента 
    keepalive_requests 100;

    # Разрешает или запрещает сброс соединений по таймауту 
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    # Будет ждать 30 секунд тело запроса от клиента, после чего сбросит соединение 
    client_body_timeout 30s;
    # В этом случае сервер не будет принимать запросы размером более 1Мб 
    client_max_body_size 1m;
    # Если клиент прекратит чтение ответа, Nginx подождет 30 секунд и сбросит соединение 
    send_timeout 30s;

    # Proxy #
    # Задаёт таймаут для установления соединения с проксированным сервером. 
    # Необходимо иметь в виду, что этот таймаут обычно не может превышать 75 секунд. 
    proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
    # Задаёт таймаут при передаче запроса проксированному серверу. 
    # Таймаут устанавливается не на всю передачу запроса, а только между двумя операциями записи. 
    # Если по истечении этого времени проксируемый сервер не примет новых данных, соединение закрывается. 
    proxy_send_timeout 30s;
    # Задаёт таймаут при чтении ответа проксированного сервера. 
    # Таймаут устанавливается не на всю передачу ответа, а только между двумя операциями чтения. 
    # Если по истечении этого времени проксируемый сервер ничего не передаст, соединение закрывается. 
    proxy_read_timeout 30s;



    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    # Включаем сжатие gzip
    gzip on;
    # Для IE6 отключить
    gzip_disable "msie6";
     # Добавляет Vary: Accept-Encoding в Headers
     gzip_vary on;
     # Cжатие для всех проксированных запросов (для работы NGINX+Apache)
     gzip_proxied any;
     # Устанавливает степень сжатия ответа методом gzip. Допустимые значения находятся в диапазоне от 1 до 9
     gzip_comp_level 6;
     # Задаёт число и размер буферов, в которые будет сжиматься ответ
     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
     # Устанавливает минимальную HTTP-версию запроса, необходимую для сжатия ответа. Значение по умолчанию
     gzip_http_version 1.1;
     # MIME-типы файлов в дополнение к text/html, которые нужно сжимать
     gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
     # Минимальная длина файла, которую нужно сжимать
     gzip_min_length 10;

  # Подключаем конфиги конкретных сайтов 
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*;

  ### Далее определяем localhost
  ### Сюда отправляются запросы, для которых не был найден свой конкретный блок server в /vhosts/
  server {
     server_name localhost; # Тут можно ввести IP сервера
     disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
     listen 80 default_server; # Указываем, что это сервер по умолчанию на порту 80

     ### Возможно, понадобится чётко указать IP сервера
     # listen      192.168.1.1:80 default_server;

     ### Можно сбрасывать соединения с сервером по умолчанию, а не отправлять запросы в бекенд
     #return      444;

    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    location @fallback {
       error_log /dev/null crit;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
       proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       access_log off ;
    }
  }
}
```

Что изменить, чтобы сайт загружался стабильно?

Comment: А вы уверены, что именно в nginx проблема, а не бекенд глючит?

Comment: Уверен. Перезаписываю nginx загружается отлично. Второй раз уже идет ошибка. И это постоянно.

Comment: Фразы «Перезаписываю nginx загружается отлично» я не понял

Comment: Почитайте, что такое 502: https://ruhighload.com/post/Ошибка+502+bad+gateway+в+Nginx     Не там источник проблемы ищете.

Comment: @KAGGDesign теоретически может быть и там, ошибку 502 может порождать ещё куча всяких разных причин, помимо описанных по ссылке